# Linker Trouble once more

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

Hi I been trying for 2 hours trying to find the reason for these errors:

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

It is on console setting and I checked for the subsystem and it is  also set on console. I do not know what is wrong, also I am new to C++ so explain slowly (Please)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int Range1, Range2, Guess, Midpoint, NumOfGuess;
string Selection;
bool GameQuit = false;

void MidpointReset()
{
    Midpoint = rand() % 31 + 0;
    Range1 = rand() % Midpoint + 0;
    Range2 = rand() % 31 + Midpoint;
}
void RangeReset()
{
    Range1 = rand() % Midpoint + Range1;
    Range2 = rand() % Range2 + Midpoint;
}
int Main()
{
    MidpointReset();
    while (GameQuit == false)
    {
        cout << "1. Show me the range" << endl
            << "2. I want to guess the number" << endl
            << "3. Quit" << endl
            << "4. Reset MidPoint"
            << "Enter your selection :" << endl;
        cin >> Selection;
        if (Selection == string("1"))
        {
            cout << "Between " << Range1 << " and " << Range2 << endl;
            RangeReset();
        }
        else if (Selection == string("2"))
        {

            cout << "Enter your guess:" << endl;
            cin >> Guess;
            NumOfGuess += 1;
            if (Guess == Midpoint)
            {
                cout << endl << "Right! It took you " << NumOfGuess << " trials!";
                GameQuit = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (Selection == string("3"))
        {
            MidpointReset();
        }
        else if (Selection == string("4"))
        {
            cout << "Thanks for playing!";
            GameQuit = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Sorry " << Selection << "Is a invalid selection";
        }
    }
    cout << "Please press any key to exit...";
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Main()` should be `main()`

Answer (score 0):

Lowercase matters in `main()`

Switch `Main()` to `main()` to let the entry point be found.

As a sidenote:

```
cout << "1. Show me the range" << endl
        << "2. I want to guess the number" << endl
        << "3. Quit" << endl
        << "4. Reset MidPoint"
        << "Enter your selection :" << endl;

....
else if (Selection == string("3"))
{
    MidpointReset();
}
else if (Selection == string("4"))
{
    cout << "Thanks for playing!";
    GameQuit = true;
    break;
}
```

3 and 4 are exchanged in the help selection: 4 exits, 3 resets the midpoint.

Comment: Really? That is what is wrong with it? :O

Comment: Yes, compiles/links just fine on MSVC with this simple change. I'd call it a typo.

Comment: Darn they were switched! I forgot to fix that! 
Thanks again! :D

Comment: There are some other problems with the script as well so I'll have to fix them as well but now it can be easier since m isn't capitalized :)